# Choices regarding IP restrictions on web request

Tags: php, ip, web-hosting

Didn't really know what title to give this question so I hope its acceptable.

I am using a system which has an API.  I don't have a lot of control over this system, but one thing I need for security reasons is for it to be locked down to my IP.  This works, so now the system can only be accessed from my IP.

Now, I have built a custom app which uses the above API.  This app is hosted on a server which is different from my IP address.  Therefore, when I try to make the API call it fails due to it being restricted.  I know this is the case, because if I run the app locally from my location, it works without any problems.

So, the question is whats the best thing to do?  I know I could add the IP address of the server which is hosting my app to the systems API.  However, I think the servers IP is dynamic which could cause problems.  I have also used things like no-ip locally to control my dynamic IP, but I cant imagine I can install this on my web server.

Looking for thoughts as to how I can overcome this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why would the server have a dynamic IP address? If it's a web server, it needs to have a static IP address or else people would have a problem accessing the site via a domain name.

Comment: IP alone is not great security, how about parssing some kind of token with every request

Comment: Oh, it probably is static then.  I presumed they worked like our IP addresses.

Comment: One thing you could clarify please.  If someone goes onto my web page and clicks a button which sends a request to that systems API, does the request come from my web servers IP or the users computers IP?

Comment: The request comes from the web server's IP address not from the visitor's ISP IP address.